Laravel 11 Reverb: WebSocket Connection failed
WebSocket connection to wss://subdomain.domain.com/app/... failed
Its working on locally without any issue but in production it gives issue
here is my .env for production
REVERB_APP_ID=401132
REVERB_APP_KEY=vcgwoutdwqj3qek4ixsv
REVERB_APP_SECRET=o1jvqubryshtorosmgbz
REVERB_HOST="subdomain.domain.com"
REVERB_PORT=443
REVERB_SCHEME=https

REVERB_SERVER_HOST="server-ip"
REVERB_SERVER_PORT=8080

VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY="${REVERB_APP_KEY}"
VITE_REVERB_HOST="${REVERB_HOST}"
VITE_REVERB_PORT="${REVERB_PORT}"
VITE_REVERB_SCHEME="${REVERB_SCHEME}"

Also when starting reverb server --debug
Starting server on server-ip:8080 (subdomain.doamin.com).
Pruning Stale Connections ............................
Pinging Inactive Connections .........................
Also i ran npm run build
I need help very badly. already tryinng for weeks
Thanks in advance
i tried changing the REVERB_PORT and REVERB_HOST but no luck

Your reverb output shows port 8080, but your reverb port is 443, do you actually have a reverse proxy setup to tunnel traffic from subdomain.domain.com:443 to your reverb server running locally on 8080?

changed the port to 8080
Now
Starting server on server-ip:8080
and the port 8080 is open

Changed the Description also but still no luck

you must to set BROADCAST_CONNECTION to reverb and QUEUE_CONNECTION to 'sync'.
Here the .env file from a working Reverb server on AWS LAMP.

BROADCAST_CONNECTION=reverb 

QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync

REVERB_SERVER=reverb

REVERB_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
REVERB_SERVER_PORT=8080
REVERB_APP_ID= replace_with_your_keys
REVERB_APP_KEY=replace_with_your_keys
REVERB_APP_SECRET=replace_with_your_keys
REVERB_HOST=yourdomain.com
REVERB_PORT=443
REVERB_SCHEME=https

# if you use vite add this too, same info
VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY=replace_with_your_keys
VITE_REVERB_HOST=yourdomain.com
VITE_REVERB_PORT=443
VITE_REVERB_SCHEME=https


nothing works for me.

Hi do you find the solution bro
because i am also stuck here
localhost (http://127.0.0.1:8000/)is saying
wss://localhost:8080/app/r4klajydlrt66ofal8cc?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.4.0-rc2&flash=false' failed:
and my ENV is this in laravel 11 with reverb
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:+l5y9bR2vIa2RzICZFDery9ogQJoEDAYFE77iBrTTRw=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC
APP_URL=http://localhost

APP_LOCALE=en
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en
APP_FAKER_LOCALE=en_US

APP_MAINTENANCE_DRIVER=file
# APP_MAINTENANCE_STORE=database

PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS=4

BCRYPT_ROUNDS=12

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_STACK=single
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=chat_9
 DB_USERNAME=root
 DB_PASSWORD=

SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_ENCRYPT=false
SESSION_PATH=/
SESSION_DOMAIN=null

BROADCAST_CONNECTION=reverb
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database

CACHE_STORE=database
CACHE_PREFIX=

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_CLIENT=phpredis
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=log
MAIL_SCHEME=null
MAIL_HOST=127.0.0.1
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

VITE_APP_NAME="${APP_NAME}"


REVERB_APP_ID=214093
REVERB_APP_KEY=r4klajydlrt66ofal8cc
REVERB_APP_SECRET=ip7lrpqbd1dy54yl4njw
REVERB_HOST="localhost"
REVERB_PORT=8080
REVERB_SCHEME=http

VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY="${REVERB_APP_KEY}"
VITE_REVERB_HOST="${REVERB_HOST}"
VITE_REVERB_PORT="${REVERB_PORT}"
VITE_REVERB_SCHEME="${REVERB_SCHEME}"

